# Возможно ли читать документацию .NET не в Visual Studio (и не в браузере)?

Tags: c#, .net, документация

Можно ли скачать полную документацию .NET Framework 4.5 SDK, а также описания языков C# и XAML не используя IDE  (Visual Studio) ?

Comment: Если не в Visual Studio и не в браузере, то как? В Word файле или chm? Что Вы хотите?

Comment: @EllaSvetlaya да например в chm или pdf. Описание языка же должно существовать отдельно, а не только на сайте или в IDE. Если у меня, например нет IDE, то без постоянного подключения к интернету я не смогу читать документацию?

Comment: Можно MSDN скачать https://www.microsoft.com/ru-ru/download/details.aspx?id=20955

Comment: @NMD спасибо за ссылку, жаль что нет более свежей версии, но уже гораздо лучше

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант можно использовать вот такой инструмент "Visual Studio 2012/2013 Help Downloader". Расположен на codeplex: http://vshd2012.codeplex.com/

Позволяет скачивать документацию в локальную папку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: для просмотра скачанного нужен Help Viewer, который является частью Visual Studio.